# Creating a language selection in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

i want to add a language selection for my kivy application

i use a .csv file with the columns DE, FR, EN and a list of different names. Basically when starting the application, you get to chose the language. And when you select DE (German) everything will be in German.
This isnt working. I think it just doesnt "refresh" the content and always stays on the initial lang you select. Is there any better way to do this or how to refresh the site?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import pandas as pd
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


LabelBase.register(name='Frutiger', fn_regular="fonts/Frutiger.ttf")
csv_lang = pd.read_csv('language/lang.csv', delimiter=";")
csv_catalog = pd.read_csv('csv/catalog.csv', delimiter = ";")
Window.clearcolor = 0, 0.31, 0.624, 1


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
class Language_Select(Screen):
    pass
    
class Main(Screen):
    text_var = ["title","title2","title3","title4"]
    for var in text_var:
        locals()[var]= StringProperty()

    lang = "EN"
    title = csv_lang.loc[0, lang]
    title2 = csv_lang.loc[1, lang]
    title3 = csv_lang.loc[2, lang] 
    title4 = csv_lang.loc[3, lang]

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Now in my .kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.2
<Button>:
    background_color: (0,0.8,1,0.8)
    font_name: 'Frutiger'
    font_size: 30
<Label>:
    font_name: 'Frutiger'
WindowManager:
    Language_Select:
    Main:
<Language_Select>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        rows: 1
        padding: 50
        spacing: 50

        Button:
            
            text: "EN"
            on_release: 
                app.lang = 'EN'
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
        Button:
            text: "DE"
            on_release: 
                app.lang = 'DE'
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
        Button:
            text: "FR"
            on_release: 
                app.lang = 'FR'
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
<Main>:
    name: "main"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            id: l1
            text: root.title
        GridLayout:
            rows: 3
            cols: 1

            Button:
                id: b4
                text: root.title2
              
            Button:
                id: b5
                text: root.title3
                
            Button:
                id: b6
                text: root.title4
```

Hopefully there is something i just dont find. Google couldnt really help me since i didnt know what to search for exactly
Sincerely Pascal

Comment: You need to update the values of your `title` properties. Changing the value of `lang` will not affect the values of your `title` properties.

Comment: @JohnAnderson thank you. but how do i do this in the .kv file?

Comment: Instead of just setting `app.lang` in your `kv`, call an app method that does what is needed.